# Which DropBox installer do I have to download for use on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, dropbox

Which one should I use - Ubuntu or Debian?

The Debian one I guess since Lubuntu doesn't use nautilus. Not sure though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the one for Ubuntu, since Lubuntu actually is Ubuntu, only with a different set of default applications.